# Dynamic SQL (T-SQL) insert into (dynamic table name) using stored procedure (sp_executesql @sql)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert, dynamic-sql

I'm struggling with a stored procedure inserting values into a table.

The table name is variable, for example, Log1

This table contains the following columns: `Actual`, `Regulated`, `Supply`, `Expected`, `ControlValue` all type `float`.

The stored procedure has the same input parameters and in addition to this the table name offcource.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO    

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertIntoTable](
   @TableName nvarchar(50),
   @Actual real,
   @Regulated real,
   @Supply real,
   @Expected real,
   @Control_Value real)
AS
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON; 
  DECLARE @columnList varchar(75)
  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) -- dynamic SQL should always be Unicode

  SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO dbo.' + @TableName +  '([Actual],[Regulated],[Supply],[Expected],[Control_Value])
        VALUES('+@Actual+','+@Regulated+', '+@Supply+','+@Expected+','+@Control_Value+')'  

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql    
END
```

Comment: So what are you struggling with?

Answer (score 3):

First, the fact that you need to resort to dynamic SQL indicates a serious database design problem: You have multiple tables that stores the same entity, holding some identifiers in the table name.
Taking your example, assuming the tables you have are named `log1`, `log2`...`logn`, you should replace them with a single table called `log`, and have that number as another column in this table.

Having said that, I realize that in many cases, changing the database structure is not an option - and for that reason I'll show you a workaround for your problem (anything other than changing the database structure is by definition a workaround and not a solution).

The first thing you want to do is to use `sysname` as the data type for the table name instead of your current `nvarchar(50)`.
`sysname` is the data type used internally by SQL Server for all identifiers.

The second thing you is to make sure the table actually exist, and that it has the columns you expect. This can easily be done using the built in `information_schema.columns` system view.

Next, you want to treat your parameters as parameters - not to concatenate them into the dynamic SQL string, but pass them as parameters to `sp_executeSql`.

And finally, you want to safeguard against funky chars in the table name, so you use `QUOTENAME` when concatenate it to your SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertIntoTable](
   @TableName sysname,
   @Actual real,
   @Regulated real,
   @Supply real,
   @Expected real,
   @Control_Value real)
AS
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON; 

  DECLARE @ColumnCount int;
  SELECT @ColumnCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM Information_schema.Columns
  WHERE Table_Name = @TableName
  AND COLUMN_NAME IN([Actual],[Regulated],[Supply],[Expected],[Control_Value])

  IF @ColumnCount < 5 RETURN;


  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) -- dynamic SQL should always be Unicode

  SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) +  '([Actual],[Regulated],[Supply],[Expected],[Control_Value])
        VALUES(@Actual, @Regulated, @Supply, @Expected, @Control_Value)'  

  EXEC sp_executesql 
      @sql, 
      N'@Actual real, @Regulated real, @Supply real, @Expected real, @Control_Value real',
      @Actual, @Regulated, @Supply, @Expected, @Control_Value
END
```

For a more detailed explanation, check out my blog post entitled [The do’s and don’ts of dynamic SQL for SQL Server](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/12/the-does-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql-for-sql-server/).

Comment: I know it's not the usual way. It's for a temporary setup, creating a table for each log, I can analyze results easily using Microsoft Power BI.  At least for so far, I have investigated it.

Comment: "indicates a serious database design problem... you should replace them with a single table called log, and have that number as another column in this table" for MSSQL versions that don't support partitioning, there is no other option than this "manual partitioning" when you're dealing with very large tables.

Comment: @IanKemp while your claim is true, usually that's not the reason why people divide their tables like this.

Answer (score 2):

Generate dynamic statement correctly and execute `sp_executesql` using parameters. Probably your actual error is `Error converting data type nvarchar to real.`, because you are trying to concatenate text (`N'INSERT INTO ... VALUES('`) and numbers (`@Regulated, @Supply, ...`). Of course, consider carefully what @ZoharPeled explained in his answer.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertIntoTable](
   @TableName nvarchar(50),
   @Actual real,
   @Regulated real,
   @Supply real,
   @Expected real,
   @Control_Value real)
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @err int
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

    SET @sql = 
        N'INSERT INTO dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' ([Actual],[Regulated],[Supply],[Expected],[Control_Value]) '+
        N'VALUES (@Actual, @Regulated, @Supply, @Expected, @Control_Value)'  

    EXEC @err = sp_executesql 
        @sql, 
        N'@Actual real, @Regulated real, @Supply real, @Expected real, @Control_Value real',
        @Actual, @Regulated, @Supply, @Expected, @Control_Value

    RETURN @err 
END
```