# Using ISNULL(MAX(@Variable) returns Variable, not numeric value as expected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, isnull

I have a stored procedure running which is looking for a ID Name in a Variable table (v) as a summary of other database tables (a, b, c etc.). As not all tables have the ID called ID I stored them in this Variable table.

This shall be used to get the max ID from the corresponding table.

When running the following command everything is fine and I get the max ID for the corresponding table:

```
DECLARE @TableMaxID INT

SELECT @TableMaxID  = ISNULL(MAX(TableID_a),0) 
FROM DB.SCHEMA.Table_a

PRINT @TableMaxID
```

Running this query I correctly get the maximum ID form table a - '59'

As I want to use a variable in this command I tried the following

```
DECLARE @TableMaxID INT
    ,@TableIdName NVARCHAR (50)
SET @TableIdName = 'TableID_a'

SELECT TableMaxID  = ISNULL(MAX(@TableIdName),0) 
FROM DB.SCHEMA.Table_a
```

Running this causes an error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'TableID_a' to data type int.

When using the `SELECT` command only I do understand what is going on - as I get the name of the `@TableIdName` variable instead of the numeric value '59'

```
DECLARE @TableMaxID INT
        ,@TableIdName NVARCHAR (50)
SET @TableIdName = 'TableID_a'

SELECT ISNULL(MAX(@TableIdName),0) 
FROM DB.SCHEMA.Table_a

PRINT @TableMaxID
```

Returns the name of the variable which is 'TableID_a'

I am a bit confused. What am I doing wrong here. Is there a way to use the variable as I am trying to or am I getting something completely wrong.

Comment: The short answer is one cannot use a variable value as column name in a query because T-SQL doesn't expand it like a macro. It is necessary to build and execute a dynamic SQL statement string in code. That said, passing column and table as parameters suggests a design flaw, IMHO. See [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60845103/dynamic-sql-t-sql-insert-into-dynamic-table-name-using-stored-procedure-sp).

Answer (score 0):

If you put a string as parameter to the `MAX` function you get the string back (and not the maximum value of the column with same name):

```
SELECT MAX('TableID_a') -- output TableID_a
```

So you have to use a dynamic SQL statement to create the SQL statement and execute. You can use a stored procedure like this to get the maxmimum column of a specific table:

```
-- procedure to get the maximum value of a column of a specific table.
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMaxValue @tableName VARCHAR(100), @columnName VARCHAR(100)
AS
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(100)
SET @sql = 'SELECT MAX(' + @columnName + ') FROM ' + @tableName;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

You can call the created stored procedure `GetMaxValue` like this:

```
EXEC GetMaxValue '<name-of-table>', '<name-of-column>'
```

But keep in mind this call is equivalent to the following `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT MAX(<name-of-column>) FROM <name-of-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a variable in a expression its value will be used in the expression, not the value of an object which's identifier is equal to the variable's value.

You seem to want dynamic SQL, i.e. creating the text of a query in a variable and then execute this query.

```
DECLARE @maxid integer;
DECLARE @idcolumnname sysname = 'di';
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT @maxid = isnull(max(' + quotename(@idcolumnname) + N'), 0)
       FROM elbat;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, N'@maxid integer output', @maxid = @maxid output;

SELECT @maxid;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=add9ff7424e8725343accf2e5eec5b2b)

Some things to note:

- You should use `sysname` instead of some `[n][var]char` for object names. `sysname` a special data type explicitly for object names.
- You should use `quotename()` on object names prior to concatenating it to the query to make sure they're properly quoted in the query. Otherwise errors or even the possibility of SQL injections can occur.

Comment: Thanks sticky bit,
would like to understand a bit more about your sysname comment.
Does this mean I shall always use the sys name variable instead of a "nvarchar" when handling items such as dbnames, schemas, tables, columns as variables?
(Do not really understand what you mean by "object names")

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Object names are the names of objects. Like tables, etc..